# web application using Python web.py

Tags: python, web.py

I have built a audio recorder and used Google Now services to do vocal recognition. They worked fine on my PC.

Now I am thinking about taking a step further and put it on web to allow user give vocal orders remotely.

I used Python's web library and saw hello world demo work on both my PC and android phone browser. I then tried to replace the GET method of the hello world with the previous codes that does the recognition. When the codes ran, my computer could still do the vocal recognition but my phone could not display the contents.

I wonder what I am missing here?(Maybe I am just being naive here..) Is it because I used too many libraries on my PC and phone is simply not compatible with them? Thanks.

Here's the codes.

```
import voice_recognition
import web

class SpeechRecognition(object):

    def GET(self):
        return voice_recognition.main_recognition()
    #return "are you serious?"


app=web.application(('/','SpeechRecognition'),globals())
app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're correct in running your app as part of the GET method in class SpeechRecognition().

The next step is to run your application as CGI or WSGI. See the API web.application() on http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/api.

So update the class to something along the lines of:

```
class SpeechRecognition(object):

    def GET(self):
        wsgifunc(return voice_recognition.main_recognition())
```

Note: I'm trying to do a similar thing to you, but haven't cracked it just yet, but I know I'll need to run my app on www.mysite/myapp with WSGI to run the app.